# Saving document-based application with table view in swift

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, cocoa

I've created a very simple macOS application in swift that only contains a tableView. The rows of the table view display the attributes of a class.

Now I thought about saving this to a file. I've already done a similar thing a long time ago in Objective-C, but a lot has changed.

After searching a while I haven't found out how to do this. Maybe I've searched for the wrong keywords, but here is what I found out already:

1) I can utilize the data function in Document.swift

2) I somehow need to return the data in this function

What is still missing to complete this, is how to return the data of a table view in the data function.
More precisely: How to encode the tableView? Which functions should I use?

Searching this topic has just confused me, because I found too much information, for this quite simple problem. It got even more complicated since a lot of information is about iOS...

So, maybe some of you can give me some hints on how I can achieve saving my tableView to a file?

Thanks a lot!

Best regards

Comment: Do you want to save the table view or the data provided by the datasource?

Comment: I would like to save all information showed in the table view and be able to load the back into the table view.

Comment: Does the table view get the information from a datasource?

Comment: Yes. I've got an array called tableViewData. I also have an arrayController for the bindings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot/should not save a `TableView`, which is a UI element containing your data, to a file. What you want to do is to serialize the data that is fed into the `TableView` and then save it to disk and then read it back to restore the TableView once the user relaunches your app.

For a tutorial on how to do this, I highly recommend this one:

https://medium.com/commencis/swift-4s-codable-one-last-battle-for-serialization-30ceb3ccb051

However, for that to work, you first need to conceptualize how your data is structured, so that you know exactly what you need to do. Usually, TableView’s depend on arrays of items, which have several properties that need to be serialized. The serialization should follow the pattern of an array containing items with keys to identify each property you want to save.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and the tutorial! I understand it and this essentially explains on how I can code and decode my data.
I have an array called "tableViewData". It contains classes "Person" (just contains basic types like string, int, bool).
So in order to save my data I need to encode this array. Got it.
I'll try this, but your reply helped me very much!
Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Glad to help. :) However, you should accept the answers on this site if you think they have answered your questions. This is good etiquette on this site.

Comment: Yep. I know. I wanted try it out first ;) Unfortunately, I think I missed a few things... This whole coding/decoding is not completely clear for me. I just used basic types in my person class (like the struct in the tutorial), but it says "Argument type 'Person' does not conform to expected type 'Encodable'".
What did I miss?

Comment: It is impossible to know without your showing the code you are writing. Please ask another question containing the code you wrote and the error you got.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Maybe I know what's missing. I'll first try to sort it out myself and if this will not work, I'll ask again :) Because of your answer I have a starting point. Thanks again :)